# Extracting On-behalf-of property from emails in ICC

Tags: filenet-p8, filenet, ibm-content-collector

We are enabling record management for emails.
ICC with email connections for Microsoft exchange is being used for declaring emails as records

We have a requirement for maintaining the *on-behalf-of* property on mails in case the mail is sent by a user whose been delegated other user's mailbox.

But available system metadata for email don't have any property for this information. Is there a way we can extract this information from emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In email system metadata there is a property named *'Originating User'* which gives the name of the actual user who have sent the email in question.

So the *'From'* property will be populated with the user on whose behalf the mail has been sent and the *'Originating User'* property will be populated with actual user sending a mail.